# CREATE TABLE query with non-unique Index

Tags: sql, ms-access, indexing

In MS Access, what is the data definition query syntax for creating a table with a field that has an index that allows duplicate values.  I can create a table with field indexed with unique values, but can't figure out how to allow duplicate values (The equivalent of “Yes (Duplicates OK)” in the table design dialog.

The following SQL creates a table and adds a **unique** index to the PN field.

```
CREATE TABLE [AllocatedPNSales]
(
    ID AutoIncrement CONSTRAINT PrimaryKey PRIMARY KEY,
    PN Text(255) CONSTRAINT PNIndex UNIQUE,
    [Profit Center] Text(255),
    [Ship Year] INTEGER,
    Sales DOUBLE
);
```

I can add an index that allows duplicate values in the index after creating the table with this SQL statement:

```
CREATE INDEX PNIndex ON AllocatedPNSales (PN);
```

Does anyone know how to do it directly in the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Frustratingly, the documentation for [CREATE TABLE statment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql) shows *index1* and *index2* in the syntax:

> CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE *table* (*field1* *type* [(*size*)] [NOT NULL] [WITH
>   COMPRESSION | WITH COMP] [*index1*] [, *field2* *type* [(*size*)] [NOT NULL]
>   [*index2*] [, …]] [, CONSTRAINT *multifieldindex* [, …]])

However, it describes *index1, index2* as placeholders for a [CONSTRAINT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/constraint-clause-microsoft-access-sql) defining a single-field index. The only choices for a single-field constraint seem to be `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE`, `NOT NULL`, or `REFERENCES`. Given that, it doesn't appear possible to create a general (non-unique) index within the `CREATE TABLE` statement.